# Is there a way to increment the value being passed from the form?

Tags: reactjs

I have a form which is taking 'ID' as an input and adding it to the table.
My requirement is that once the value is submitted,the value in the  should be auto incremented.
Like for example. if i made an entry with id:4,name : xyz,age:34,email:ghy@gmail.com   upon clicking add button the value is entering correctly in the table but the  for Id should be automatically updated as 5.

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './Todo.css'

class Todo extends Component {

  state = {    edit: false, id: null, mode:false,  
    students: [
      { id: 1, name: 'kiwi', age: 21, email: 'kiwi@email.com' }]
}


    onSubmitHandle(event) { 
      event.preventDefault();
      this.setState({students: [...this.state.students, {id:event.target.id.value,name: event.target.item.value,age:event.target.xyz.value,email:event.target.email.value}]  })
        event.target.item.value = '';
        event.target.id.value = '';
        event.target.email.value = '';
        event.target.xyz.value = ''};




     render() 

          {    
           return<div>


                 <form  onSubmit={this.onSubmitHandle.bind(this)}>
                 <label >ID</label>
                   <input type="number"  name="id" className="item"  />
                 <label>Name</label>
                   <input type="text" name="item" className="item"  />
                   <label>age</label>
                   <input type="number" name="xyz" className="item"  />
                   <label>email</label>
                   <input type="text" name="email" className="item"  />
                   <button className="btn-add-item">Add</button>
                   </form>
                   <table id='details' >{this.state.students.map(abc => (<tr><td>{abc.id}</td><td>{abc.name}</td><td>{abc.age}</td><td>{abc.email}</td>

                    </tr>))}</table></div>  
              }
            }

              export default Todo;
```

the event.target.id.value = should be intialised to prev value plus one i.e 2 instead of a blank value.

Answer (score 1):

Just change the line you reset the id, add plus one to the previous:

```
  this.setState({students: [...this.state.students, {id:event.target.id.value,name: event.target.item.value,age:event.target.xyz.value,email:event.target.email.value}]  })
        event.target.item.value = '';
        event.target.id.value = parseInt(event.target.id.value)+parseInt(1);
        event.target.email.value = '';
        event.target.xyz.value = ''};
```

Comment: its not working .1 is getting concatenated.I want the value to be incremented as 2.instead it is becoming 11.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can just add one while setting the state as @Oner mentioned.
or even you can just show the incremented id in the table in your map i.e.

```
<table id='details' >
  {
    this.state.students.map(abc => (<tr><td>{Number(abc.id) + 1}</td><td>{abc.name}</td><td>{abc.age}</td><td>{abc.email}</td></tr>))
  }
</table>
```

Comment: its not working .1 is getting concatenated.I want the value to be incremented as 2.instead it is becoming 11.

Comment: Thats because your id is a string you can convert it to a number using
Number(abc.id) +1